# Как соединить строки из файла?

Tags: python

Есть текстовый файл с большим количеством строк. Нужно соединить строки: первую со второй, третью с четвертой итд. То есть, по идее, после каждой нечетной строки удалить /n.
Вот что пробовалось, как-то не получилось:

```
with open('dss2.txt','r+', encoding="utf8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("dss2.txt", 'w', encoding="utf8") as fp:
    for n, line in enumerate(lines):
        if n % 3 != 0:
            line.rstrip('\n')
            fp.write(line)

print(lines)
```

Comment: `первую со второй, вторую с третьей, третью с четвертой` - эмм, покажите на небольшом примере, пусть входной файл содержит строки "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" - что будет в результате?

Comment: в результате получатся строки "ab", "cd", "ef" и тд, строк всего четное количество

Comment: Где здесь соединение второй с третьей?

Comment: Ошибка, исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как-то так правильно наверное:

```
        if n % 2 == 0:               # правильная проверка на нечётность
            line = line.rstrip('\n') # не забываем присвоить в переменную
        fp.write(line)               # следим за табуляцией
```

- проверка на нечётность это `n % 2 == 0` (нулевой остаток от деления на 2, поскольку в питоне первая строчка это нулевая)
- обрезанную строчку нужно присвоить обратно в переменную
- выводить нужно все строки (у вас лишняя табуляция)

И смотрите после этого сам файл, а то, что печатается у вас в конце, это исходный файл.

Ещё можно в `enumerate` указать вторым параметром `1`, чтобы нумерация привычно начиналась с 1, а не с 0. И условие тогда можно проверять просто `if n % 2:`.

Comment: А, после Вашего изменения все заработало, спасибо большое)

Comment: @user483286 Я исправил. Не сообразил, что в питоне нумерация с нуля

Answer (score 1):

Первый цикл читает строки из файла парами. Второй печатает пары строк убирая из первой строки последний символ:

```
with open('dss2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    pairs = tuple(zip(*[f] * 2))

with open('dss2.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for s1, s2 in pairs:
        print(s1[:-1], s2, sep='', end='', file=f)
```

> ```
> $ cat dss2.txt 
> a
> b
> c
> d
> e
> f
>
> $ py join-strings.py 
>
> $ cat dss2.txt 
> ab
> cd
> ef
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Замена **replace()** один из способов

```
some_text = 'Some Text1 \nSome Text2 \nSome Text3'

some_text = some_text.replace('\n', ' ')
```

**Пример**

```
text_document = open('test.txt', 'r')

text_r = text_document.read()

text_r = text_r.replace('\n', ' ')

text_document.close()

text_document = open('test.txt', 'w')

text_document.write(text_r)

text_document.close()
```

Comment: Не каждый перевод строк надо убрать,  через один. В 1ой, 3ей, 5ой и т.д.

Comment: Нужно не все строки соединить между собой, из строк "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" должны получиться "ab", "cd", "ef". Строк парное количество

Answer (score 0):

читаем и пишем одновременно (пишем в новый файл):

```
flag = True
with open('test.txt') as f, open("test_2.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for n in f:
        if flag: n = n.strip()
        fp.write(n)
        flag = not(flag)
```